# On atheists going to hell

Tags: jahannam

Clearly Allah mentions in the Quran that those who do not believe in the religion of Islam will abide in hell. But one needs to ponder over the existence of God before accepting it. Many brilliant scientists reject the existence of God. Richard Dawkins,who is an evolutionary biologist has pretty solid logics against the exist ce of God.Will he still go to hell since he couldn't be convinced that Islam is the proper religion and unlike other kafirs and musrikhs,he didn't worship idols rather he thought about the existence of a supernatural creator.

Comment: It seems like you are just another victim of Scientology. If you want to talk about "Evolutionary Biology", the biggest Scientist alive is Michael Ruse & he has clearly stated that the only reason he rejects God is because of "Problem of Evil" (which is an emotional argument rather than logical) !! Plus, how are you connecting Atheism with Science? You do know 80-85% Scientists in the history of Science were not Atheists! Even today, top intellectuals like Elon Musk are not Atheists! Every field in Science, be it Chemistry, Maths, Physics, Computer Science, Biology, were created by Theists!

Comment: If you agree that Allah clearly mentions in the Quran that those who do not believe in the religion of Islam will abide in hell then what is the purpose of this post?

Answer (score 3):

"Will he still go to hell"

According to the Qur'an anyone who deny the Day of Judgement (deny God) will go to hell

> "Woe, that Day, to the deniers, Who deny the Day of Recompense. And
> none deny it except every sinful transgressor. When Our verses are
> recited to him, he says, "Legends of the former peoples." No! Rather,
> the stain has covered their hearts of that which they were earning.
> No! Indeed, from their Lord, that Day, they will be partitioned.
> Moreover, they will surely burn in Hell, and then be told, “This is
> what you used to deny.”

Qur'an 83:10-17

Allah knows best.